# Mix of Stateful and Stateless flutter UI not getting updated

Tags: animation, flutter, stateful

Using stateful widgets causing stale widgets to be displayed

I have a UI that receives update text updates over the network. When an update comes in, I wish to first show it in red, then have it slowly fade to black as the message's age increases. If a new message comes in from the same source, I wanted to replace the text of the old message with the new message, then have the text fade from red to black all over again.

When I use a Stateful widget with a RestartableTimer, and I first start my UI, everything seems to work fine. However, as soon as the *second* message comes in from a particular source, that's where things break. If I use a plain Text() to display the new message, it works just fine. But if I use a Stateful widget to display the text and fade from red to black, the UI remains stale and no amount of updating seems to do the trick.

My hierarchy (with layout-specific stuff removed) looks like:

```
Stateful Container for different sources
|
List View
|
+--- Stateless Custom Widget
     |
     +-- Stateless Text (displays the source)
     |
     +-- Stateful Custom Text class
<repeated for each source>
```

If I replace my custom class with a plain Text(), then suddenly the text updates just fine (but there's no fading of color).

Stateless Custom Widget

```
  Widget _CreateDataTable() {
    const Color start_color = Colors.red;
    const Color end_color = Colors.black;
    const Duration fade_len = Duration(seconds: 10);
    var read_time = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        _data.data.timeSeconds * 1000,
        isUtc: true);
    String date_text = read_time.toLocal().toString();
    List<String> labels = ["Temperature", "Humidity", "RSSI", "Last Reading"];
    List<Widget> data = [
      Text(_data.data.temperature.toStringAsFixed(2) + " C"),
      Text(_data.data.humidity.toStringAsFixed(2) + "%"),
      Text(_data.rssi.toString() + " dB"),
      FlashText(date_text, start_color, end_color, read_time, fade_len),
      // Text(date_text),
      //
      //  IF I COMMENT OUT FlashText AND UNCOMMENT Text, EVERYTHING
      //  WORKS FINE. IF I KEEP IT AS IS, I ONLY SEE THE FIRST EVER
      //  MESSAGE AND NEW MESSAGES, WHICH I CAN CONFIRM RECEIVING VIA
      //  debugPrint, ARE SEEMINGLY IGNORED.
    ];

    var rows = List<Row>();
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) {
      rows.add(Row(children: [
        IntrinsicWidth(child: SizedBox(width: 10.0)),
        IntrinsicWidth(child: Text(labels[i] + ":")),
        IntrinsicWidth(child: data[i]),
        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
      ]));
    }
    return Column(children: rows);
```

Stateful Custom Widget

```
class FlashText extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color _color0;
  final Color _color1;
  final DateTime _start;
  final Duration _duration;
  final String _text;

  FlashText(
      this._text, this._color0, this._color1, this._start, this._duration);

  @override
  _FlashTextState createState() {
    debugPrint("Creating state for $_text - $_start");
    return _FlashTextState(_text, _color0, _color1, _start, _duration);
  }
}

class _FlashTextState extends State<FlashText> {
  Color _color0;
  Color _color1;
  DateTime _start;
  Duration _duration;
  String _text;

  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;

  _FlashTextState(
      this._text, this._color0, this._color1, this._start, this._duration);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Text(_text,
        style: TextStyle(color: Color.lerp(_color0, _color1, _GetT())));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    RestartableTimer(_duration ~/ 30, _Update);
  }

  double _GetT() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    return min(1, max(0, now.difference(_start).inMilliseconds /
    _duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()));
  }

  void _Update() {
    if (_GetT() < 1.0) RestartableTimer(_duration ~/ 30, _Update);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change the design of the `FlashText` widget and use the `didUpdateWidget` method to rebuild when the widget text changes.

I have implemented below a full app using a text field and a button to simulate the text coming from the server.

I think it is more or less what you need but it might require some tweaks.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _cont = TextEditingController();

  String text = "qwertrrr";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: _cont,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("Test"),
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  text = _cont.text;
                }),
          ),
          FlashText(text, Colors.red, Colors.black, 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlashText extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color0;
  final Color color1;
  final int duration;
  final String text;

  FlashText(this.text, this.color0, this.color1, this.duration);

  @override
  _FlashTextState createState() {
    return _FlashTextState();
  }
}

class _FlashTextState extends State<FlashText>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<FlashText> {
  Animation<Color> _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;

  Timer timer;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(FlashText oldWidget) {
    if (widget.text != oldWidget.text) {
      _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Text(
      widget.text,
      style: TextStyle(color: _animation.value),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: widget.duration));
    _animation = ColorTween(begin: widget.color0, end: widget.color1)
        .animate(_controller)
          ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    _controller.forward();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That led me on the right track. Here's what I've learned.

1) State subclasses shouldn't contain the actual state they wish to display. Use the corresponding widget to hold it. 
2) Use the State classes `widget` property to access that information (I didn't realize it even existed, the tutorials are all so bare bones that they never mention it). When I removed my fields from State and added them to the Widget, the text was fixed.
3) When wanting to display something related to time, hold the timer-related mutable state in the state class (e.g. an animation object, timer callback).